# How to fit SwiftUI content to split view layout margins?

Tags: swiftui, uikit, appkit, swiftui-navigationview

I have a sidebar in NavigationView with searchable and a grouped list that both inset properly to the largeTitle. However when I want to place additional views in the sidebar, I have trouble aligning them to match the width/insets of the searchable text field or the list sections or the largeTitle. `padding(.horizontal)` doesn't match.

How can I add padding or insets to match these system elements? I've tried using layoutMarginGuide and readableContentGuide and these have wider layouts that don't match the search bar or table. See the screenshot - how can I align the Picker to the largeTitle or list row inset?

[image]

And here is sample code

```
import SwiftUILayoutGuides

struct SidebarComprehensionTab: View {
    @SceneStorage("comprehensionItemSelection") private var comprehensionSelection: String?
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 0) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                Picker("", selection: $comprehensionSelection) {
                    Text("Vocabulary").tag(1)
                    Text("Kanji").tag(2)
                    Text("Lookups").tag(3)
                }
                .pickerStyle(.segmented)
//                .fitToReadableContentWidth()
                .padding(.horizontal) // Neither of these approaches work.
            }
        }
        .searchable(...)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: Unable to reproduce the issue with available code. Could you please share the minimal reproducible example? Tested in iPhone 14 pro, iOS 16.2